# Social share button rendering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, css, haml

I'm using [social-share-buttons](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button) but I can't seem to get them to render correctly.

I have followed the steps correctly (it's required in both the application.js and application.css) and my code (HAML) is:

```
=social_share_button_tag("Gradezilla rules", url: "http://gradezilla.com", popup: "true")
```

But next to the button it is showing: `Share To" href="#">`

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this?

Comment: did you try `<%= social_share_button_tag("Gradezilla rules", :url => "http://gradezilla.com") %>`?

Comment: yup that doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when I had first implemented this gem, the install hadn't worked properly, so I did

```
rails generate social_share_button:install
```

again and now it works...